# How to fill 3D model hole

Tags: modeling

I am new to 3d modeling and I encountered this hole while modeling.

[image]

What is the easiest way to cover this hole?
If you need more info please reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch to editmode

[image: Editmode]

select the 4 adjacent vertices

[image: Vertices]

and press **f**

[image: New face]